# Does Laravel Blade templating engine affect performance?

Tags: html, laravel, performance, render, laravel-blade

I'm asking myself if the Laravel Blade templating engine has an impact on the performance of HTML rendering?

According to the documentation:

> Blade is the simple, yet powerful templating engine provided with Laravel. Unlike other popular PHP templating engines, Blade does not restrict you from using plain PHP code in your views. In fact, all Blade views are compiled into plain PHP code and cached until they are modified, meaning Blade adds essentially zero overhead to your application. Blade view files use the .blade.php file extension and are typically stored in the resources/views directory.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, complex and nested Blade templates effect on performance but not tangible because laravel compile and cache blade files.